# How to highlight different type of codes in JS or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm doing my first project for my university grade and I would like to code a "paste" service for different type of languages: php, javascript, c, etc. You know, something similar to pastebin, pastie...

I would like to know how I can highlight the code depending of the language. I mean, if there is a plugin that does and how to handle the different languages.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of sites, including the Google Code Playground ( http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/ ), use CodeMirror:  http://codemirror.net/

Answer (score 3):

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ - that'll do

For the language, the easiest thing is just ask when the user uploads the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same solution as Stack Overflow.

[Help: Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

[Google Code Prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)

It will try to determine language itself, but you can specify.

Comment: Definitely, I think I will use CodeMirror for that.

Thanks to all for the answers ;)